# Manually placing Rooms in Altium does not create a rooms

Tags: altium

I am currently creating a pcb that will, at some point in future, be placed in a case that is not known yet. Therefore, the final PCB shape/size and connector placement is not determined yet.

I began to route functional groups in themselves, intending to not route the connections to other functional blocks yet, until everything has been set.

In order to move the groups easily, I would like to use rooms. There are options to place rooms via Design - Rooms - *different options for room placement*. i would like to use this option instead of having the ECO generator generate rooms from my schematics, as im more flexible with their shape if placed manually.

However, placing a room manually does not actually place a room. When starting to place a room, the cursor changes, I can click to e.g. set a polygons points. On finishing the placement, Altium runs through some design rule checks and then ... nothin happened. No Room has been placed. (Same if i select the components and tell Altium to place a room around the selection).

I have used this before. Not sure why its not working now. Maybe there are some options I am not aware of?

**SOLVED**

yes, it was an option that I was not aware of: Design - Board Layers and Colors - Show / Hide tab - Rooms was set to hidden.

Comment: Does it only work if routes have been placed around those components selected as a room?

Comment: No difference for routed/unrouted components or if traces have (not) been selected, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the "solution": The view configuration.

When i checked the rules for my board, I realized that there were many more rules in the "rooms" than i expected. Means the rooms ive been trying to place were placed.

They were simply set to "hidden" under Design - Board Layers and Colors - Show/Hide Tab ...